# Run appxbundle on a simulator

Tags: windows-8.1, windows

I have a maybe a small problem.

My task is to test a windows 8.1 tablet app. I have no tablet here, so I installed the Visual Studio 2013 Express and the Windows Phone SDK.

If I start the "windows phone application deployment" and try to start the *.appxbundle file, I get an error

> a packaging error prevented this application from installing

I sent this back to the developer, he means the app is made for tablets and have to be tested on tablets.

So my question:

- Is it somehow possible to simulate windows 8.1 tablet on a windows 8.1 system?
- How to install the .appxbundle file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, install the app with windows power shell

> add-appxpackage C:\myapp.appx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the app in a tablet then there is no need of a Windows Phone SDK or any simulator. You can install the app in your Windows 8.1 pc/desktop, and it will be the same as it will be on a tablet, because a windows store app is common for tablet and pc.

And to install the .appxbundle you can refer to this [link](http://www.niallbrady.com/2013/11/07/how-can-i-create-windows-8-1-applications-and-then-deploy-them-with-system-center-2012-r2-configuration-manager/) (from step 6).